# ListPlot with background image?

Tags: graphics, plotting

I need repetitive plots like this below. I invented that I refuse to use pen and I will plot the points in Mathematica, then change opacity, then change contrast and voula get the points to the graph -- or better idea perhaps just transparency -- well this is many of the ways how you can do it in Photoshop.

**How can I have a background image so I can just insert the mathematica plot on the plot?**

> **Input [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3mES.png)**
>
> **Goal better than hand-drawn versions such as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cZkn.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7piK.png)**

*P.s. Extra upvotes for fun answers!*

[image]

**Data**

```
points2 = {{0.30, 2.25}, {0.39, 2.45}, {0.35, 2.45}, {0.19, 
    2.28}, {0.15, 2.22}, {0.03, 2.1}, {0.13, 2.13}, {0.19, 
    2.17}, {0.18, 2.25}, {0.01, 2.68}, {0.24, 2.22}, {0.22, 
    2.18}, {0.26, 2.17}, {0.24, 2.30}, {0.27, 2.50}, {0.29, 
    2.12}, {0.28, 2.13}, {0.29, 2.14}, {0.27, 2.21}, {0.28, 2.17}};

where 0.30 corresponds to the 30 on the x-axis and so on.
```

Comment: `Overlay` is probably what you want.

Comment: @Verbeia how are `Inset` and `Overlay` different?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3mES.png"];

Graphics[{
  Inset[img, {0.2, 2.2}, Automatic, {0.55, 0.7}],
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[points2]
 },
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.1
]
```

[image]

I'll leave you to work out the alignment yourself but it can all be controlled with the parameters of `Inset`.

Or for interactive placement you can [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) the image, plot your points, copy the points graphic, then double-click the Raster graphic and paste the points into it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you +1! I love to combine Mathematica to real life :D